# Editing formula within multiple calculated fields concurrently

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a pivot table with monthly run-rate forecast. 
e.g. on the 5th of Jan it would be [number]/5 *31

I change it every week so 5th/ 12th/19th etc.

Only problem is I have lots of fields like this and lots of tables and lots of sheets. Is there any way to update the calculated fields in bulk?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should consider now() formatted to give the week. Then call that value in your calcs... should update with every change of week

Comment: Thanks Mike, I agree but wasn't able to comment yet. So thanks! :) Should I delete and/or put a comment instead?

Comment: Get in quick and put my suggestion with now() :)

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciate your help.